# JavaFX: Buttons with same width and size to text

Tags: java, layout, javafx, javafx-8

A button can always auto-resize its width to its contents (`textProperty`), but I need something more.

I have a group of Buttons; each has its own text. I need all the buttons to have the same width, but at the same time, I want this same width to be as small as possible (such that none of the buttons have extra spaces nor ellipsis).

I thought it would be easy, until I realized that `getWidth()`, `getlayoutBounds.getWidth()` and `getlayoutBoundsInParent().getWidth()` do not return the calculated width.

Initially I was directly binding all the properties (`prefWidthProprety()` to `widthProperty()` etc), but eventually I fell back to manual mode to investigate:

```
Button buttonA; // With original text "hello world"

buttonA.setText("Testing new String. This is very long so the width will be very big.");
buttonA.layout();
buttonA.requestLayout();

Platform.runLater(() ->
{
    System.out.println(buttonA.getWidth()); // Gives me old value
    System.out.println(buttonA.getlayoutBounds.getWidth()); // Gives me old value
    System.out.println(buttonA.getlayoutBoundsInParent().getWidth()); // Gives me old value
});
```

So now, what options do I have?

Comment: Did you try to put all the button on VBOX? Make the VBOX width to USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, and the bind the buttons width properties to the vbox width property

Comment: Does *nobody* bother to read documentation any more? The standard Oracle [layout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/size_align.htm#JFXLY133) has exactly this as an example. It says: *"You can go through the trouble of determining the height and width of each button and then setting the preferred size of each button to the greatest height and width of the buttons in the set. An easier option is to let the layout panes do the work."*, and then proceeds to show you how to solve *exactly* this problem without computing sizes (*or*, @Zoltanik, using bindings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer you question regarding the layouting:

You can request the layout on the parent of the `Button` like:

```
buttonA.setText("Testing new String. This is very long so the width will be very big.");
buttonA.getParent().layout();
buttonA.getParent().applyCss();
```

I have added [`applyCss`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss--) and removed `requestLayout`:

> If required, apply styles to this Node and its children, if any. This
>   method does not normally need to be invoked directly but may be used
>   in conjunction with Parent.layout() to size a Node before the next
>   pulse, or if the Scene is not in a Stage.

Comment: Okay, it's working... `applyCss()` is not the crucial part, it's calling parent's `layout()` that does the job.

Comment: In case of undecorated `Button`s you are right, but if you set some CSS on the them, it becomes "crucial" :)

Comment: Though this is not the way to make the buttons the same width in the first place. Just let the `VBox` (or whatever layout pane you are using) do the work for you.

Comment: @James_D Unfortunately, they are placed as a row, not column.

Comment: @Jai then you would use a `GridPane`.

Comment: @James_D GridPane can do that? It's not just about being uniform in size, but also using only as much space as the text needs without overflowing.